# How to use split_on_whitespace in elastic search?

Tags: search, elasticsearch

I want to use split_on_whitespace in search query, but couldn't figure it out. Query will have a string like : "hello world". I don't want to split the query word

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all make sure that the mapping of the field that you want to search is not analysed. So that ES will not analyse the words in the field and store it as a single text.

so your mapping will be something like:

```
    curl -XPUT localhost:9200/index_name -d '{
      "mappings": {
       "type_name": {
           "properties": {
               "field_to_search": {
                   "type": "string",
                   "index": "not_analyzed"
               },
            ...(other fields)
          }
       }
    }
    }
```

Then you can perform a term query on the field.

```
curl -XPOST localhost:9200/index_name/type_name/_search -d '{
    "query": {
        "term": {
           "field_to_search": "hello world"
         }
     }
 }
```

You can take a look at the difference between term query and match query of elasticsearch to understand why term query is required.

Comment: I think the question is even though there is an analyzer that does split the query but specific field not to split. Hope I am not wrong.